# Create list of custom stop words in elastic search using java

Tags: java, elasticsearch

To enhance my search result obtained from elastic search I want to increase my stop word library from my java code. Till now , I am using the default list of stop analyzer which do not have the interrogative words in list like What,Who,Why etc. We want to remove these words and some additional words from our search when querying for result. 
I have tried  code from here(the last ans) [tried](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17625385/tokenize-remove-stop-words-using-lucene-with-java)

```
PUT /my_index
{
"settings": {
"analysis": {
  "analyzer": {
    "my_analyzer": { 
      "type": "standard", 
      "stopwords": [ "and", "the" ] 
    }
  }
}
```

}
}

**This code in java.**
But It wasn' working for me. 
Important Query

**How to create our own list of stopwords and how to implement it in our code with query**

```
QueryStringQueryBuilder qb=new QueryStringQueryBuilder(text).analyzer("stop");
            qb.field("question_title");
            qb.field("level");
            qb.field("category");
            qb.field("question_tags");
            SearchResponse response = client.prepareSearch("questionindex")
            .setSearchType(SearchType.QUERY_AND_FETCH)
            .setQuery(qb)
            .execute()
            .actionGet();
            SearchHit[] results = response.getHits().getHits();
            System.out.println("respose-"+results.length);
```

Currently I am  using default stop analyzer. Which just stop a limited stop words like

*"a", "an", "and", "are", "as", "at", "be", "but", "by",
      "for", "if", "in", "into", "is", "it",
      "no", "not", "of", "on", "or", "such",
      "that", "the", "their", "then", "there", "these",
      "they", "this", "to", "was", "will", "with"*

But I want to increase this library.

Comment: You need to add StopFilter for adding  custom stopwords. Could you share your java code which you have developed so far ?

Answer (score 1):

You're on the right track.  In your first listing ([from the documentation about stopwords](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/using-stopwords.html)) you created a custom analyzer called `my_analyzer` for the index called `my_index` which will have the effect of removes *"and"* and *"the"* from text that you use `my_analyzer` with.

Now to actually use it, you should:

1. Make sure that you've defined `my_analyzer` on the index you're querying (`questionindex`?)
2. Create a mapping for your documents that uses `my_analyzer` for the fields where you would like to remove *"and"* and *"the"* (for example the `question_title` field):
3. Test out your analyzer using the Analyze API

   `GET /questionindex/_analyze?field=question.question_title&text=No quick brown fox jumps over my lazy dog and the indolent cat`
4. Reindex your documents

---

Try this as a starting point:

```
POST /questionindex
{
    "settings" : {
        "analysis": {
            "analyzer": {
                "my_analyzer": { 
                    "type": "standard", 
                    "stopwords": [ "and", "the" ] 
                }
            }
        }
    },
    "mappings" : {
        "question" : {
            "properties" : {
                "question_title" : { 
                    "type" : "string", 
                    "analyzer" : "my_analyzer" 
                },
                "level" : { 
                    "type" : "integer" 
                },
                "category" : { 
                    "type" : "string" 
                },
                "question_tags" : { 
                    "type" : "string" 
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```